# Read port into Bash script variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am currently writing a bash script to automate my nodeJS deployment on my ubuntu test server. The port is listed within a the bin/www file. In the example line below the port is 3003 that I need to get in a variable of my script:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3003');
```

Do I need to parse the file with some regex in order to get the port number in a variable to work with it?

Comment: It lets you specify the port via an environment variable. Why don't you just have your script specify a port, instead of having the script try to guess which port it'll end up on by default?

Comment: It's not clear from this question what your actual problem is. The only line of code you've posted looks like it should work fine as-is (and also isn't actually bash).

Comment: (as that other guy says, this code is to let bash tell node which port to use; it's not the other way around -- bash should tell node what to use, instead of having bash try to figure out what node is hardcoding as a default).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The question as I understand it is how would one parse that port out in a bash script.

Comment: @German, right, but that's the wrong approach to take. The code is written to make it easy to someone to override the port from bash. Why work against the grain and do something fragile (parsing out the default port, and needing to maintain that code even if the javascript changes), instead of what the developer intentionally made easy (overriding the default port)?

Comment: I agree that his approach is not good. My comment was not aimed at justifying his approach. It was aimed at clarifying his intention, because you said "It's not clear from this question what your actual problem is".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse that 3003 out in a bash script you'll need to get the line in question, then pipe it to something that can get the value out. Something like:

```
grep 'normalizePort' <file_with_the_port> | grep -oE '[0-9]+'
```

You'll need to play around with it to get you to where it works for you.

However, as others have pointed out, that won't give you the port. That will only give you the default port. The real port is in an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) (that's what `process.env` means in this case), thus in a bash script you'd *probably* be able to access that PORT variable like so:

```
APP_PORT=${PORT:-3003}
```

You ought to read more on environment variables. Ideally you shouldn't be parsing ports out of files, unless those files are specifically created for storing config in a machine-friendly format like YAML or JSON.